# php close session and delete data

Tags: php, session, sessionid

Hy everyone, I know there are a lot of posts regarding closing sessions but I have kind of a "strange" situation. So, basically. You come to my page, and You don't have to log in. I immediately start a session and grab Your session_id. On the page, You can upload an image and enter some data, at which point (when you click the save button) a php script makes a folder named as Your session_id and puts the image and data (as a generated html page) into that folder. Now, I want to be able to delete that folder once when You live my page. Is that possible? If not, is it ok to delete the folder after let's say 24 hours? I know I can use session_destroy to destroy the session, but how can I first delete Your folder and then close the session? Any advice? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have done till now...?? You need to show your code...

Comment: @Adarsh I don't think showing code is going to help much with suggestions on how to delete a folder...

Comment: Sessions are destroyed once a browser is closed automatically (by default). It sounds like you would want to run a cron-job to delete directories that haven't been updated within 24 hours. However in terms of scale-ability that might be rough on the server depending on the number of sessions you have going.

Comment: @Chris: My intention was just to know whether he had given it a try on his own before putting up his question. His question just gave a rough idea as to what he wanted but spoke nothing about his attempts... No hard feelings gogo_rulez... Happy to help if you have done your part...

Comment: @Adarsh i didn't try anything actually. I am a little confused on the whole idea of deleting sessions. What I mean is, I don't know when the session should end, how to end it, and at which point to delete the users folder.

Comment: @ gogo_rulez: Well I guess I would suggest you to go through tutorials viz. w3school and manual (php.net)... Try to figure it on your own... If you get caught anywhere... Bring it up here with your attempts (in the form of code)... Most of us, rather, all of us will definitely help you out... That is how you will be learn better...

Answer (score 0):

PHP session hander is your friend here. http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandler.php

The gc function can check and clean your inactive sessions.

Comment: wait but, why do you want to generate html files? cant you generate them on the fly? may be cache it ?

Comment: I generate the html file beacuse I want the user to be able to "generate" a page with the information he entered. Nothing too complex or difficult..

Comment: Is the user going to download the file? or is it going to be view-able later on?

I know this is off topic. My option would be to not to generate and save a file. Instead you can generate the html file on the fly. if you want the person to download it you can set header to do so. if your system makes so much files i guess your disk quota will eventually run out. PHP is about generating html its a template engine.

Comment: Yes the user is going to download the file but as a PDF, there's a button which the user click and then he gets the PDF generated from the page that was created when he saved his data.. It just came to me.. would it be ok to delete the users folder when the download starts/ends?

Comment: okay i think what you need is a cronjob. im not sure if your hosting service offers you this feature.

When creating the pdf you first check if the file exists. if it does then just download. or else make the file and download. a cron job is run lets say every 24 hours and then you delete all the old files. 

assuming you are deleting files when you delete the session see my suggestion on using the session handler in php. its the best way to do this.

Comment: ok, Your comment sounds exactly like what I'm trying to do. I'll have a look in session handler. Thanks!